# Physics.CheckSphere always give false (Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm trying to create objects that mark the cell that I can visit. I mark them with red square:

[image]
[image]

My code for creating objects:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class SpawnCheck : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject checkObject;

    public bool canSpawnCheck = true;
    Vector2 boxSize;

    public GameObject spawnedObject;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Debug.Log("Into spawn check");
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        Debug.Log("Enter trigger collision");
        canSpawnCheck = false;

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Target") {
            Debug.Log ("Found Target");
        }

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Wall") {
            canSpawnCheck = false;
        }

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Check") {
            canSpawnCheck = false;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other) {
        Debug.Log("Exit trigger collision");
        canSpawnCheck = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        Debug.Log ("canSpawnCheck " + canSpawnCheck);

        if (canSpawnCheck == true) {

            Vector3 currentPosition = this.gameObject.transform.position;
            Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3 (Mathf.Round (currentPosition.x), Mathf.Round (currentPosition.y),0);

            Debug.Log ("Physics.CheckSphere " + Physics.CheckSphere (spawnPos, 5));

            if (!Physics.CheckSphere(spawnPos,5)) {

                spawnedObject = (GameObject)Instantiate (checkObject, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);

                this.gameObject.GetComponentInParent<AILerp> ().possibleTargets.Add (spawnedObject);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**My problem:** as `Physics.CheckSphere(spawnPos,5)` always return `false` my code spawns too many red squares and spawn them upon each other. I want red squares to be created only once and never created on walls (white squares).

Comment: I just want to point out one thing. You should use `Equals()` method instead of `==` for String comparison in the `OnTriggerEnter2D` method.

Comment: Have you checked that there are indeed one or more colliders overlapping with the sphere defined by the center **spawnPos** and radius 5?

Comment: @greenPadawan how I can check it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your *Check(Clone)* GameObject has `Box Collider 2D` attached to it. Therefore every physics function you must use should be `Physics2D.something` not `Physics.something`. Notice the keyword there "2D".

If you use just `Box Collider` without the 2D in it, then you can use `Physics.something`. So, `Physics.CheckSphere` cannot be used with a 2D collider.

*Check(Clone)* is a `SpriteRenderer`, 2D Collider is appropriate. You just need to use one of the [`Physics2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.html) overlap functions such [`Physics2D.OverlapBox`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapBox.html), [`Physics2D.OverlapArea`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapArea.html) or [`Physics2D.OverlapCircle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html). Which ever one you prefer.